# Почему я не могу обратиться к свойству объекта?

Tags: javascript

Вот мой объект

```js
console.log(per);
console.log(per.Easy);
```

В консоль выводит
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему вторая консоль возвращает undifined

Comment: Когда вы проставляете значение свойства `Easy`? Такое ощущение, что после того, как делаете `console.log`.

Answer (score 1):

Откройте закладку "Консоль" в "Инструментах разработчика" браузера.

```js
var per = {};
setTimeout(function(){
  per.Easy = "this is very easy";
  per.Hard = "but this is hard";
}, 50);
console.log(per);
console.log(per.Easy);
```

Comment: Повесил setTimeout() и заработало.

Comment: У меня объект из редакса берется

Comment: @sinevitch это не решение, а пример поведения, которое Вы наблюдаете

Comment: Я просто не могу понять, как тогда определять объявился объект в redux, или еще нет. В redux сохраняется запрос с сервера

Comment: this.props
        .onGetAllQues('ru')
        .then((result) => {
          result;
          let per = this.props.allquestions;
          setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(per.Легкий);
          }, 5000);

        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });

Comment: `let per = this.props.allquestions; console.log(per.Легкий);` - ?

Comment: Это в зависимости от языка. Формируется объект